# Stack based merge sort C

Tags: c

I'm having trouble converting a recursive based merge sort to a stack based merge sort. Having double recursive calls in a function throws me off. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `mergesort` iteratively, merging adjacent slices of 2^k elements, from k=0 until 2^k >= n. It is quite straightforward, there is no need for a *stack conversion* of the recursive algorithm.

You will need extra space to perform this, typically the same size as the dataset.  You can allocate this space with `malloc` or use automatic storage if that's not too large (stack based allocation).  But this memory requirement is similar to that of the recursive implementation.

Merging slices of 2^k elements is slightly less efficient if the total number of elements is not a power of 2, and it performs more comparisons and uses upto twice as much memory but the overall complexity is still O(n*log(n)) in the worst case, and a clever implementation can bring it down to O(n) for the sorted case.

Try this approach, I will post some code after you show your own attempts.

Comment: @panw1: No attempt?  Did you give up on this problem?

Comment: Both top down (recursive) and bottom up require extra space. Given a second temp array of the same size as the original array, then both top down and bottom up sorts work with indices (as opposed to the alternate top down method that repeatedly allocates and frees partial arrays).